# DialogFragmment and AppCompat

Tags: android, android-actionbar, styles, android-appcompat, dialogfragment

its my first question here so i am excited and just want to say its looks like awesome community.

and now for my question:

I try to use class that extends DialogFragment, sadly to display the dialog i am forced to use AppCompat theme otherwise its throws an error.

1. Is there a way to show the dialog without using AppCompat theme?
2. I need to display ActionBar and it does not displayed when I use AppCompat, what will be the optimal solution?

   ```
   <resources>

   <!-- Base application theme. -->
   <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
       <!-- Customize your theme here. -->

       <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
       <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
       <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
   </style>
   ```

^ this is the style i am using, it works fine except no action bar.

the error i get if i dont use appCompat:

```
08-28 20:31:31.905 24099-24099/com.hadas.yotam.friendsapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                            Process: com.hadas.yotam.friendsapp, PID: 24099
                                                                            java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
```

Mainfest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<permission android:name="com.hadas.yotam.friendsapp.provider.READWRITE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.hadas.yotam.friendsapp.provider.READWRITE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".EditActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"/>
    <activity android:name=".SearchActivity"
              android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"/>
    <activity android:name=".AddActivity"
              android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"/>
    <provider
        android:authorities="com.hadas.yotam.friendsapp.provider"
        android:name="com.hadas.yotam.friendsapp.FriendsProvider"
        android:exported="true"
        android:readPermission="com.hadas.yotam.friendsapp.provider.READWRITE"
        android:writePermission="com.hadas.yotam.friendsapp.provider.READWRITE"/>

</application>
```

Thanks in advance,
Yotam.

ful error trace:

08-29 19:14:54.413 12111-12111/com.hadas.yotam.friendsapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
             Process: com.hadas.yotam.friendsapp, PID: 12111
             java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:343)
             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:312)
             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:277)
             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDialog.setContentView(AppCompatDialog.java:80)                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AlertController.installContent(AlertController.java:214)                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.onCreate(AlertDialog.java:256)                                                                                at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:396)                                                                                at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:268)                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.onStart(DialogFragment.java:406)                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:2000)                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1102)                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:742)                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517)                                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5118)                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:794)                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:610)                                                                                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Welcome! You'll find that asking one question at a time will get you a much better response rate. Consider editing your question so that you ask one question at a time.

Comment: Please edit question and add your DialogFragment code.

Comment: @ianhanniballake i understand adn agree but in this case the 2 questions related because i need either 1 of them.

Comment: @ShadowDroid i am currently not at home will do so when i get back.
anyway i dont belive the class code is related.
how ever i will add now more information i have avilable.
thank you for your time.